# List KeyError Python

Tags: python, json, for-loop, keyerror

I'm trying to append a list with values from an API for the Glassdoor.

When I get a response back from this API, I get info such as the name of the company, ratings, CEO, a bunch more info, and lastly if the company is owned by a parent company, I get that too.

My problem is when I append my list with all this info, if the company I'm getting a response from the API doesn't have a parent company, I don't want it to skip extracting the other relevant data like name, CEO, etc. I want it to print out the available data for that companies response, then where the parent company is print NA.

Each company I get a response from the API may have a different length/vary in the available data.

For example:

```
comp_info.append(data['response']['employers'][0]['name'])
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve, Apple doesn't have a parent company, while LSI Corporation does. I'm not sure how to approach this problem?

[APPLE, Tim Cook, 4.5, N/A, Computer Hardware]
[LSI Corporation, Some Guy, 4.6, Avago Technologies, Computer Hardware]

Comment: To receive help debugging your code, you need to post your actual code and the actual error you have along with the sample data necessary.  In short you need to use `if` statements to test the conditions and choose alternate behavior.  Note that a `list` in python doesn't raise `KeyError` (as indicated in your question summary) since a list doesn't have keys.

Comment: @dsh, Agreed. He's probably referring to the `data` dictionary when he's talking about the `KeyError`

Comment: @brianpck  I agree with you. I mentioned it because it appears as though he doesn't have a clear enough understanding to identify the cause of the issue and a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand your question, but Python has a concept of "Better to ask forgiveness than permission" that might be helpful here:

```
try:
    comp_info.append(data['response']['employers'][0]['name'])
except KeyError:
    comp_info.append("N/A")
    # or print ("N/A")
```

Please clarify your question if you are looking for different handling than this.

Comment: I still get a KeyError, even though my code reads: comp_info.append(data['response']['employers'][0]['parentEmployer'].get('name', 'N/A'))

Comment: comp_info.append(data['response']['employers'][0].get('parentEmployer', 'N/A'))

Comment: @RossJohnson Unless you include more detail, I can only speculate: it's not clear at what level the error occurs. If only one key could be missing, use `get`. If any level of the data-structure is missing, use my `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
comp_info.append(data['response']['employers'][0].get('name', 'N/A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comp_info.append(data['response']['employers'][0].get('parentEmployer', 'N/A'))
```